# Slickgrid: resetActiveCell() does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, tablecelleditor

1.
When I leave the grid, I call resetActiveCell(), but the cell remains selected. Is there another statement to deselect the last selected cell?

2.
I am using the longText editor. When I leave my grid and call resetActiveCell() the editor does not close.

Any thoughts what I could do?

Answer (score 2):

A little late but...
I call both.  (Assuming you have a selection model plugin loaded)

```
var clearGridSelection = function () {
    grid.resetActiveCell();
    grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectedRows([]);
};
```